# How to work with ag-grid "min" "max" values

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs, typescript, ag-grid

how to handle editing of min and max values in ag-grid for angular, so that min value can't be bigger than max value and vice versa?

Let's say we have a data structure like this to put into ag-grid

```
{
  data: [
    {
      id: '0',
      one_min: 23,
      one_max: 42,
      two_min: 1,
      two_max: 5,
    },
    {
      id: '1',
      one_min: 20,
      one_max: 40,
      two_min: 10,
      two_max: 15,
    }
  ]
}
```

Then i would dynamically create the columnDefs with something like this:

```js
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() data!: any[];
  columnDefs: ColDef = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.forEach(data => Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
      this.columnDefs.push({
        field: key,
        editable: true,
        ...
      })
    })
  }
}
```

But how to figure out the composit fields 'one' and 'two' and how to tell the grid that min value can't be bigger than max value and vice versa?

The table in this example should lead to 4 rows with 2 columns

| one_min | one_max | two_min | two_max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23 | 42 | 1 | 5 |
| 20 | 40 | 10 | 15 |

I couldn't get any answer from the official docs but i'm sure there must be an easy way of doing this.

---

### Solution

What we want here is the valueSetter parameter of ColDef.
So data generation should look something like this:

```js
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() data!: any[];
  columnDefs: ColDef = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.forEach(data => Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
      this.columnDefs.push({
        field: key,
        editable: true,
        valueSetter: (params) => {
          const colId = params.column.getColId();
          const colIdSplit = colId.split('_');
          const key = colIdSplit[0];
          const param = colIdSplit[1];
          if (param.toLocaleLowerCase() === 'min') {
            const result = !!params.data[`${key}_max`]
                ? parseInt(params.newValue, 10) <= parseInt(params.data[`${key}_max`], 10)
                : true;
            params.data[colId] = result ? params.newValue : params.oldValue;
            return result;
          }
          if (param.toLocaleLowerCase() === 'max') {
            const result = !!params.data[`${key}_min`]
                ? parseInt(params.newValue, 10) >= parseInt(params.data[`${key}_min`], 10)
                : true;
            params.data[colId] = result ? params.newValue : params.oldValue;
            return result;
          }
        return true;
        },
        ...
      })
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: The final result you seek is unclear to me and may be to others. Maybe you could add a [Markdown Table](https://www.markdownguide.org/extended-syntax/#tables) demonstrating what your data would transform into.

Comment: Added a markdown table

Comment: This is still unclear to me. You talk about min and max values, as if those values effect the resulting table, yet the table you added seems taken straight from the data (without the `id` properties).

Comment: Id value should neither be shown nor beeing editable.
If i would change the first "one_min" value from "23" to "43" it should not be possible because the corresponding field "one_max" is smaller than the entered value.

Comment: When you say, "it should not be possible," do you mean that the table would not display a row for id 0? In other words, are you trying to filter the data such that if a min value is larger than a max value, then it is filtered out? Why not filter the data before passing to the table data? That seems much cleaner. Me personally, I would separate the logic that filters my data from my code that displays my data.

Comment: To me it seems like you are not familiar in working with ag-table. Thank you for trying to understand my question and for your time.